# Change chain_specs to mint custom total supply of custom coin

Tags: substrate-node-template, chainspec

So, I am working with substrate-node-template . I already changed `tokenSymbol` and `tokenDecimals`,i want to `mint specific amount to native coin`(initially) , but confused where to start . Any insight would be useful .

Answer (score 1):

Modify this part https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/blob/4f8ddf87776bcb2c5df1babc2725a397afa145ea/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L195-L197.

Add more genesis accounts with balance in that `Vec`. It's a tuple `(who, amount)`.